# Xamarin Form - Constantly getting Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'google_app_id'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The google_app_id is not something I defined myself, I think is generated upon building google_play_services.json in the Android project.
However, I have been having encountering so many times of getting the follow

> Error CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for
>   'google_app_id'

It solve it sometime when I clean/rebuild the Android project, but it just come back once a while, even if I didn't change anything on Android project but the Shared Project code only :(

Anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: clean building your android project will solve the error

Comment: @G.hakim Like I mentioned in my question, I did clean and it resolve, but it will come again randomly.  I don't want to waste my time to clean and rebuild every time it happen.

Comment: That is not an error you get randomly it happens because of the ResourceDesigner that is auto-generated the only way to regenerate it is a clean & build

Comment: @G.hakim But I didn't modified anything in Android project at all.  All I did was just modify the xaml file in PCL and all of sudden it gives me such error :/

Comment: What is the Xamarin forms version you have installed in all your projects?

Comment: @G.hakim I am using Xamarin.Forms. (3.0.0.446417) and I just updated my VS 2017 to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

:/ At the end it come to a situation even the clean and rebuild said all successfully, but when I try to deploy it gives me the same error.
So what I did at the end is do a Repair on Visual Studio, then create a blank new Xamarin project and move everything into it....
Then now, even it showing the error, I can still deploy... 
I didn't solve it, but at least I can deploy :(

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem and resolved it by adding 
`<GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />`
in the Android.csproj, like this :

```
<ItemGroup>
 <None Include="app.release.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
 </None>
 <None Include="app.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
 </None>
 <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
 <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\mydb.db3" />
 <None Include="google-services.json" />
 <None Include="packages.config" />
 <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
 <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So, google-services.json appears now twice in the project, but the error disapeared.

Hope this helps someone...